how to change page direction to RTL in radzen blazor studio app
I have a web application with radzen blazor studio. I added localization to the application. So it added CulturePicker.Razor page and CulturePicker.cs class.
This was the CulturePicker.cs class
<RadzenDropDown @bind-Value="@culture" TValue="string" Data="@(new [] { new { Text = "العربية (المملكة العربية السعودية)", Value = "ar-SA"}, new { Text = "English", Value = "en" } })"
    TextProperty="Text" ValueProperty="Value" Change="@ChangeCulture" />

and this is the [Change="@ChangeCulture"] method
protected void ChangeCulture()
{
    var redirect = new Uri(NavigationManager.Uri).GetComponents(UriComponents.PathAndQuery | UriComponents.Fragment, UriFormat.UriEscaped);

    var query = $"?culture={Uri.EscapeDataString(culture)}&redirectUri={redirect}";

    NavigationManager.NavigateTo("Culture/SetCulture" + query, forceLoad: true);
}

What I need is when the user changes the culture (language) the layout of the page (direction) change from RTL and LTR

According to this new release, we just need to add dir=”rtl” attribute to the html tag in your layout to enable right-to-left mode. May I know whether you've tried it?

I found a sample here which used ThemeService: https://blazor.radzen.com/theme-service?theme=material3&rtl=false

yes my friend i've tried. but the problem is if i but this code to mainlayout page the application starts in RTL which it shouldnot be , it should start in english culture with LTR layout.  after the user select arabic language ( culture) the application changes to RTL layout.   can you help me @Tiny Wang.......    and my code in the other comment

this is my code @Tiny Wang
void SetDIR(string direction)
{
if (JSRuntime is IJSInProcessRuntime sr)
sr.InvokeVoid("document.body.setAttribute", "dir", direction);
else
JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("document.body.setAttribute", "dir", direction);
}
void SetRTL() => SetDIR("rtl");
void SetLTR() => SetDIR("ltr");  but when i call SetRTL on the method ChangeCulture It doesnot reponse

Thanks a lot for your update but your codes can't work in my side as I don't have Culture/SetCulture component. Could you please comment NavigationManager.NavigateTo("Culture/SetCulture" + query, forceLoad: true); and call SetLTR() method to see whether it worked or not? In my side, I create a new blazor web app in VS and even if I don't have Radzon component library, it should work as well.

Yes my friend i comment NavigationManager.NavigateTo("Culture/SetCulture" + query, forceLoad: true); and the SetLTR() method  works fine in this case .. but i need this method which i commented . so what should i do..  @
Tiny Wang

Hi Ibrahim, pls see my update below......

thanx alot my friend but when i tried to use this code when the app start it give's me this error...                                                                                                                Uncaught NotSupportedError: Failed to execute 'define' on 'CustomElementRegistry': the name "blazor-ssr-end" has already been used with this registry.

Hmmm, just like you see there's no CustomElementRegistry in the code snippet you shared in this case. I'm afraid there's something wrong in codes maybe you can address the problematic line to see more information. If you can't solve it, try to comment that line and see whether it caused a list of other errors when compilation, then I'm afraid you will find the reason for the error message you shared.

See my update below. I think it's somewhat ugly but it might be a workaround as it really work. I create a js method in App.razor component, which will call a .Net method. In the .Net method, it will change the direction of body element. Then when the culture dropdown option changed, it will change the direction to rlt, then a navigation will apply the change so that you will see it's chagned. If there's no navigation, you need to call SetRTL() method as well. I tried to use StateHasChanged() but it can't make the chagne applied. I tried to use Cascading parameter but I failed. I trust there will be a better solution but I've tried my best.
protected async Task ChangeCulture()
{
    await JS.InvokeVoidAsync("SetRtl");
    // SetRTL(); 
    _navigation.NavigateTo("/counter" + query, forceLoad: true);

}

<body dir="@CurrentDirection">
    <Routes />
    <script src="_framework/blazor.web.js"></script>
    <script src="_content/Radzen.Blazor/Radzen.Blazor.js?v=@(typeof(Radzen.Colors).Assembly.GetName().Version)"></script>
    <script>
        window.SetRtl = () => {
            DotNet.invokeMethodAsync('BlazorWebAppRadzen', 'changeDirection');
        }
    </script>

</body>
</html>

@code{
    public static string CurrentDirection = "ltr";

    [JSInvokable]
    public static void changeDirection()
    {
        CurrentDirection = "rtl";
    }
}

==============================
Firstly, I found radzen-blazor-components-v5 already support rtl appearence, the document mentioned

One of the most significant updates in this major version is the
introduction of the highly anticipated Right-to-Left (RTL) support.
All Radzen Blazor Components now fully support RTL direction .... To
enable it, just add dir=”rtl” attribute to the html tag in your
layout.

Following this action plan, I found this case which could work well in blazor app, no matter we used Radzen or not. I had a test with a new .net 8 blazor web app and adding codes below in Whether.razor component and it worked. You can also add the methods into your ChangeCulture method.
@page "/weather"
@attribute [StreamRendering]
@rendermode InteractiveServer
@inject IJSRuntime JS

<PageTitle>Weather</PageTitle>

<h1>Change Direction</h1>
<button @onclick=SetRTL>
    RTL
</button>
<button @onclick=SetLTR>
    LTR
</button>

@code {
    void SetDIR(string direction)
    {
        if (JS is IJSInProcessRuntime sr)
            sr.InvokeVoid("document.body.setAttribute", "dir", direction);
        else
            JS.InvokeVoidAsync("document.body.setAttribute", "dir", direction);
    }
    void SetRTL() => SetDIR("rtl");
    void SetLTR() => SetDIR("ltr");
}


Then I also found this sample using Radzen ThemeService. It requires to inject @inject ThemeService ThemeService and call ThemeService.SetRightToLeft({true/false}); to change the view.

